# Повторное использование CTE в том же запросе

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper

У меня в коде c# dapper выполняет запрос следующего вида:

```
const string query = @"
    ; WITH copp AS 
    (
    )
    SELECT
    FROM schedule

    ; WITH copp AS 
    (
    )
    SELECT
    FROM students
";

using (var multi = this.Db.QueryMultiple(query, parameters))
{
    var scheduleItems = multi.Read<Schedule>();
    var students = multi.Read<Student>();
}
```

При этом определение CTE для copp полностью совпадает для первого и второго SELECT'а. Я посмотрел план запроса в SSMS - выполняется каждый раз заново.

Отсюда у меня возникает вопрос: можно ли каким-то образом определить CTE один раз и использовать дважды?

По [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016) выходит, что нельзя:

> За обобщенным табличным выражением (ОТВ) должны следовать
>   **одиночные** инструкции SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE или DELETE, ссылающиеся на некоторые или на все столбцы ОТВ.

Никаких обходных путей нет?

Сижу подумываю не оформить ли cte вьюшкой, но может есть какие-то варианты обойтись без неё?

Comment: Можно преобразовать CTE во VIEW, чтобы не писать текст дважды. Но выполняться всё равно будет два раза. Чтобы выполнить только один раз, нужно сбросить результат CTE во временную таблицу и обращаться к ней - но это сработает только в случае, когда все запросы выполняются в рамках одного connection.

Answer (score 2):

Для MS SQL можно воспользоваться табличной переменной:

```
DECLARE @copp TABLE (<список колонок с указанием типов>);
INSERT @copp SELECT <запрос из вашей CTE>;
```

далее работаете с переменной `@copp` как с обычной таблицей.

```
SELECT * FROM schedule JOIN @copp ...;
SELECT * FROM students JOIN @copp ...;
```

ну или как вы там ее собирались использовать.

В вашем случае, когда все операции выполняются в одной сессии это будет работать хорошо, однако если данных в выборке для табличной переменной будет много, то возможно проседание  производительности, иногда существенное. В таком случае вместо табличной переменной стоит использовать временную таблицу или даже оставить два построения CTE, т.к. накладные расходы на вставку данных что в табличную переменную, что во временную таблицу, никуда не денутся и они могут превосходить расходы на строение CTE.

Более конкретно что-то советовать сложно - факторов много, информации о ваших БД и приложении мало => надо пробовать, измерять и выбирать. Довольно часто ранняя оптимизация запроса на небольшом тестовом объеме данных приводит к проблемам на большом объеме реальных данных, так что, могу ошибаться, но вполне допускаю, что вы торопитесь с оптимизацией.

Comment: Вот за это я и люблю so - могут подсказать вариант, который ты сам редко используешь и он тебе перестаёт приходить в голову. Табличные переменные - интересный вариант, опробую и сравню. Данных у меня мало, но спасибо за предупреждение, посмотрю где ещё можно подрезать и сравню с накладными расходами других вариантов.

Comment: @AK табличные переменные не сильно отличаются от обычных временных таблиц, но разница все же есть, например индексы на них не вешаются, поэтому и дописал про объем данных.

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, из языковых средств, с помощью которых в T-SQL можно (в соответствии с практиками повторного использования кода) определить что-то, что затем могло бы многократно применяться во `FROM` в качестве источника данных, доступны лишь обобщённые табличные выражения, представления и табличные функции.

При этом область видимости CTE ограничена одиночной DML-инструкцией, а функции и представления являются объектами уровня БД с соответствующей областью видимости. Чего-то похожего, что обладало бы областью видимости шире, чем у CTE, но меньше, чем у представлений и функций в T-SQL на данный момент нет.

Потребность эта могла бы быть удовлетворена `#`- или `@`-представлениями (по аналогии с `#`- или `@`-таблицами), если бы они существовали в T-SQL. На Feedback.Azure есть соответствующее [предложение](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32891617-module-level-table-expressions), которое было размещено более десяти лет назад на (тогда ещё) Microsoft Connect, но воз и ныне там (со статусом *Unplanned*). Может быть в том числе и потому, что подобная концепция не определена пока и в SQL-стандарте (даже в текущей, на данный момент, его версии - SQL:2016).

Поэтому да, либо дважды определять одинаковое CTE, либо создавать view (или table-valued function, если нужны параметры), либо материализовать подзапрос во временную таблицу.